# delegating initializers in structs are not marked with 'convenience'

Tags: swift

I keep getting this error and I don't understand why.

> error: delegating initializers in structs are not marked with 'convenience'

This is what I have (as an example), a `DeprecatedCurrency` and a `SupportedCurrency`.

```
struct DeprecatedCurrency {
    let code: String
}

struct SupportedCurrency {
    let code: String
}
```

I then want to add a convenience init function for converting from the deprecated currency object to the new currency object. And this is what I have:

```
struct DeprecatedCurrency {
    let code: String
}

struct SupportedCurrency {
    let code: String

    convenience init(_ currecny: DeprecatedCurrency) { // error!!
        self.init(code: currecny.code)
    }

    init(code: String) {
        self.code = code
    }
}
```

What does this error even mean and how do I fix it?

---

I know that if we don't provide a default initializer, a initializer with signature `init(code: String)` will be automatically generated for us with struct in Swift. So by the end of the day, what I am really looking for is (if possible):

```
struct SupportedCurrency {
    let code: String

    convenience init(_ currecny: DeprecatedCurrency) { // error!!
        self.init(code: currecny.code)
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try removing "convenience" from that line?

Comment: What does the fix-it suggest? (*hint hint*)

Comment: @LouFranco yes, removing `convenience` works. Is there a reason why we cannot have `convenience` init for swift?

Comment: @YuchenZhong It's still technically a convenience initialiser (in that it chains to another initialiser) – you just don't need the `convenience` keyword because there's no useful distinction between convenience and designated initialisers for structs, as you cannot chain to `super`.

Comment: @Hamish The hint suggestion is to just remove it and it works. I am hopping to get the default initializer `init(code: String)` generated by marking the `init(_ currecny: DeprecatedCurrency)` convenient. If it isn't possible, I guess I will have to just do that ...

Comment: As soon as you add any kind of explicit constructor, the default one goes away - unfortunately. I think there was talk about changing the behaviour but nothing came of it.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Just remove the `convenience`, it is not required for `struct`.

From `Swift` documentation.

> Initializers can call other initializers to perform part of an instance’s initialization. This process, known as initializer delegation, avoids duplicating code across multiple initializers.

They haven't mentioned using `convenience`. It is `convenience` in semantic but doesn't require the keyword.

```
struct DeprecatedCurrency {
    let code: String
}

struct SupportedCurrency {
    let code: String

    init(_ currency: DeprecatedCurrency) { // error!!
        self.init(code: currency.code)
    }

    init(code: String) {
        self.code = code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 21):

structs don't need the word `convenience`

Try this:

```
struct SupportedCurrency {
    let code: String

    init(_ currency: DeprecatedCurrency) { // error!!
        self.init(code: currency.code)
    }

    init(code: String) {
        self.code = code
    }
}
```

The question is not why don't we put `convenience` for structs but why *do* we put `convenience` for classes. The reason is that classes have inheritance. With a class you need to call the super class's designated constructor (not sure if that is the correct terminology, it comes from Objective-C's initialsers.. The word `convenience` marks the constructor as "not the designated constructor".

Comment: @sdasdadas It fully answered the question as originally put. High/low quality is not a function of length.

Comment: The question also asked what the error meant. Initially, you didn't answer that question. I removed ithe downvote now that you've got an actual answer.

Comment: So the worst you could say is that it wasn't complete even though the answer to the question was easily inferred by saying "structs don't need `convenience`" because that is what is going on. He put `convenience` when structs don't need convenience. Anyway, thanks for providing feedback (and removing the down vote). Many people wouldn't bother - especially after being challenged.

Answer (score 4):

One option is to add the new `init` in an `extension` of your `struct`. This way, you wont loose the `default` auto generated memberwise initialiser.

```swift
struct SupportedCurrency {
    let code: String

}

extension SupportedCurrency {
   init(_ currency: DeprecatedCurrency) {
        self.init(code: currency.code)
    }
}
```

From [Apple docs](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html#ID215)

> NOTE
>
> If you want your custom value type to be initializable with the
>   default initializer and memberwise initializer, and also with your own
>   custom initializers, write your custom initializers in an extension
>   rather than as part of the value type’s original implementation. For
>   more information, see Extensions.